# How to plot the mean of a single factor in a barplot with

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, factorial, points

I'm having trouble to create a figure with ggplot2. 
In this plot, I'm using geom_bar to plot three factors. I mean, for each "time" and "dose" I'm plotting two bars (two genotypes).

To be more specific, this is what I mean:
[image]

This is my code till now (Actually I changed some settings, but I'm presenting just what is need for):

```
 ggplot(data=data, aes(x=interaction(dose,time), y=b,  fill=factor(genotype)))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
 scale_fill_grey(start=0.3, end=0.6, name="Genotype")
```

Question: I intend to add the mean of each **time** using points and that these points are just in the middle of the bars of a certain **time**. How can I proceed?

I tried to add these points using geom_dotplot and geom_point but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
time_data = data %>% group_by(time) %>% summarize(mean(b))
data <- inner_join(data,time_data,by = "time")
```

this gives you data with the means attached. Now make the plot

```
 ggplot(data=data, aes(x=interaction(dose,time), y=b,fill=factor(genotype)))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
 scale_fill_grey(start=0.3, end=0.6, name="Genotype")+
 geom_text(aes(b),vjust = 0)
```

You might need to fiddle around with the argument hjust and vjust in the geom_text statement. Maybe the aes one too, I didn't run the program so I don't know.

Comment: Thank you very much, Stephen! Your code makes me realize how to add the points in my plot. Actually I wrote in a different way, but I organized my data as you said! 

`geom_point(data=data, aes(y="mean(b)", x = x), colour = "red", size=1.5)`

I created a "x" column to indicate where these points should be plot! It worked.

Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It generally helps if you can give a reproducible example. Here, I made some of my own data.

```
sampleData <-
  data.frame(
    dose = 1:3
    , time = rep(1:3, each = 3)
    , genotype = rep(c("AA","aa"), each = 9)
    , b = rnorm(18, 20, 5)
  )
```

You need to calculate the means somewhere, and I chose to do that on the fly. Note that, instead of using points, I used a line to show that the mean is for all of those values. I also sorted somewhat differently, and used `facet_wrap` to cluster things together. Points would be a fair bit harder to place, particularly when using `position_dodge`, but you could likely modify this code to accomplish that.

```
ggplot(
  sampleData
  , aes(x = dose
        , y = b
        , fill = genotype)
  ) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(data = 
               sampleData %>%
               group_by(time) %>%
               summarise(meanB = mean(b)
                         , dose = NA, genotype = NA)
             , aes(yintercept = meanB)
             , col = "black"
              ) +
  facet_wrap(~time)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mark! You and Stephen helped me a lot to understand how should I organize my data. I created a data set with `dose, time, genotype, b, mean(b), x`. As you can see, I created a "x" column to indicate where these points should be plot in X axis!

I also wrote:

`geom_point(data=data, aes(y="mean(b)", x = x), colour = "red", size=1.5)` to plot the points on the right coordinates. It worked!

Again, thank you very much!